# How to forward ports for X11 on Proxmox to a MV

Tags: networking, xorg, iptables, port-forwarding

Well, I read that I needed to open ports 6000-6063 and also 117 (UDP).

I tried it without luck:

```
    post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 6000:6063 -j DNAT --to 192.168.x.xxx:6000-6063
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 6000:6063 -j DNAT --to 192.168.x.xxx:6000-6063
    post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p udp --dport 117 -j DNAT --to 192.168.x.xxx:117
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p udp --dport 117 -j DNAT --to 192.168.x.xxx:117
```

Under my client, I execute:

```
ssh -Y -p xxxx root@my.ip.com
```

But I get this when I try to execute gedit:

[image]

I suppose the problem is related to  port forwarding issues. But I can't figure it out.

I already check iptables-save but everything is OK, so Idk what's going on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this: https://wiki.iihe.ac.be/Use_X11_forwarding_with_WSL

So it's easy to do. You need to remember to enable all the required ssh config sections and export $DISPLAY on .bashrc if required.